# How can I store the result of a function as an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have some code that returns the contents of a `<div>` after you press a button. I need to save the result of this function to an array. So how do I do that?

Here's my code so far:

```
var numKey = document.getElementsByClassName('num-key');

  for (var i = 0; i < numKey.length; i++) {
  numKey[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    return this.innerHTML;
  });
};
```

Comment: Instead of returning the value (which doesn't do much in an event listener) you just assign it to wherever you want. I can't imagine how you can fail to do this if you understand what your current code does.

Comment: Could you offer a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I'm going to give you the simple one just now.  First, create a global variable array, then just assign the value to that array instead of returning it:

```
myArray = [];
var numKey = document.getElementsByClassName('num-key');
var len = numKey.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
  numKey[i].addEventListener("click",function addToArray(){
  myArray.push(this.innerHTML);
}
```